# C# Prism navigationProblem

Tags: c#, .net, navigation, prism

I have two regions. A navigation region and a main region.

My navigation region contains two buttons which call the RequestNavigate method. 
The first button loads a view without any parameters

```
this.tRegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, ViewNames.VInfoMainViewUri);
```

The second button should load the same view with some parameters

```
  this.tRegionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, new Uri(ViewNames.VInfoMainViewUri.OriginalString + "" + query.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

This works fine if no view is loaded. If any view is loaded, a click on any button causes nothing.

I tried to remove every active view from my region, but this causes an error

```
IViewsCollection col = tRegionManager.Regions[args.RegionName].Views;
foreach (var obj in col)
{
   tRegionManager.Regions[args.RegionName].Remove(obj);

}
```

> The region does not contain the specified view.
>   Parameter name: view

How can I fix this probem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a new view even when there is already an existing view of the same type in the region, you need to implement the `INavigationAware` interface either in your View or your ViewModel (Prism will check first the view, and if it doesn't implement `INavigationAware` it will also check the ViewModel).

You are interested specifically in the `IsNavigationTarget` method, which tells Prism if the current instance of the View should be reused, or if another instance should be created to satisfy the navigation request. So, to always create a new View you would do:

```
public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware {
    bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

All of this is explained in greater detail in Chapter 8 of the Prism 4 documentation; they also have [an illustration of how it works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#TheRegionNavigationSequence).